# Writing and reading to a local file with Java RS

Tags: java, jersey, glassfish, data-persistence, java-ws

I've written a small web application that allows the client to POST values and then GET the sum of those values, using a glassfish server in intellij. I want the sum to persist across service restarts. Currently, the sum is being tracked with a Singleton resource so that it can be shared with a couple different classes. Is there a way that I can write and read a file in a local directory? Something like:

```
src:
     Singleton
     Rest of classes
res:
     PersistentDataFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can write the data in a local file, but it should not be in `resources` directory. Because, if you it in `resources` directory, it will become part of your `WAR` file and later, if you deploy updated `WAR` file, this file will gets override.

Now there are 2 solutions -

1) Store data in a file placed outside of your web application. However, you need to handle `multi-threading` and you have to write code for avoiding read/write of the file by more one `thread` i.e. in more than 1 `request`.

2) **Recommended Approach** - For handling such situations, storing such data in `database` is recommended approach. In this approach also, you need to handle modification of data by more than one `thread`. However, such situations can be easily handled by writing appropriate `SQL` query by which read and write can be done in a single `query` (not always possible) or maintain some `version` column or `last modified timestamp` column in database.